# Idiom, common phrase crossword puzzle challenge 2

Tags: idioms, games

Please solve this puzzle

[image]

1. A famous Chinese general with a red face
2. Too greedy; take on more than one can handle
3. Extremely insightful
4. Going back on one's words
5. Soul flying out of the sky
6. Undefeated
7. Detailedly explain the pro and con
8. Homeland destroyed
9. Return an item to the owner
10. Fly straight to the sky
11. Tiny profit
12. Like crying, like lamenting
13. Unstoppable momentum

A. die

B. 'So that's the reason'

C. A verse from 木蘭辭 (Mulan Poem); travel a great distance quickly

D. Homeless

E. Unexpected

F. Sneak pass

G. Intense situation

H. Cheerful mood, happy spirit

I. All harms and no benefit

J. Not leaving home

K. Come back to win

L. Unable to revive

*If the blank puzzle is too hard for you, you can try the one with additional hints below*

> [image]

Comment: You missed the explain of #E!

Comment: @T-Pioneer Unlike the last one, I hope this one takes you more than 5 minutes to solve

Comment: God, you edited the picture? I have to do again...

Comment: please use the spoiler syntax for answers to puzzle questions. place  >!  before the graphic you want to hide

Comment: For `K. Come back to win`, it's another word instead of `回XX術`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: @TangHo In these two games, I realize some problems: 1. Almost nobody cares about it. I posted my answer first for both two times. Maybe it's very hard to most of learner? 2. Changing too many times. Sometimes, one blank has many answer, and they're all correct. It makes me change my answer for several times. 3. Words in dialects. I don't know Cantonese well, I usually speak Mandarin Chinese in my real life. Due to this, I can't fill blanks in Cantonese by myself. My words seem too sharp, but forgive me, please, I just want to improve it and keep it going on!

Comment: @T-Pioneer I have another puzzle twice as big. 41 items. If you are interested, I can post it so you can try. (I also corrected 原璧歸趙 and 原來如此 in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 5 minutes this time - but more than 5 hours, and I don't know is my answer all correct.

> [image]

I finished 90% before hints appearing, but those 10%, I can't fill them at all until I see the hints because I heard those words really rarely.

Comment: A, B, 2, H,  L need correcting, see the puzzle with word hints, I think you can finish it now. You may have to reload the page to see the edited picture

Comment: @TangHo I'm very curious about the word "完来如此". I never heard anybody say it before, maybe it's more commonly use in Taiwan?

Comment: 魂归天国 https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%E9%AD%82%E5%BD%92%E5%A4%A9%E5%9B%BD+%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD It is a Bible phrase. And it is 原璧歸趙 and  原來如此 https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E5%8E%9F%E7%92%A7%E6%AD%B8%E8%B6%99 Maybe the hint 'Return something intact' should be changed to "return an  item to the owner'